# Remove class after 5 second on ViewportChecker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, viewport, removeclass

I'm using [ViewportChecker](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker#jquery-viewport-checker) jquery plugin, script that detects if an element is in the viewport and adds or remove a class to it.

I'm trying to hold class for 5 second, *means remove class `.invisible` after 5 second*. I've made a demo, when scroll down to the element/class then it get window view and then ViewportChecker remove `.invisible` class then add `.visible` class.

*See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/och42noo/11/)* >

**HTML:**

```
<div class='parent-div'>
<div class="a invisible"> <!-- Content -->
New blog writers everywhere are faced with a serious dilemma when they first reach the Internet and must decide which blogging platform is best for their new website. There are actually dozens of options on the market, ranging from the basic blog settings of the social networks to the self-hosted open sources software solutions.
</div>
    <br></br>    
<div class="b invisible"> <!-- Content -->
New blog writers everywhere are faced with a serious dilemma when they first reach the Internet and must decide which blogging platform is best for their new website. There are actually dozens of options on the market, ranging from the basic blog settings of the social networks to the self-hosted open sources software solutions.
</div>

</div> <!--main div end-->
```

**JS:**

```
// For Class a
$('.a').viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
    classToRemove: 'invisible', // Class to remove before adding 'classToAdd' to the elements
    offset: 2, // The offset of the elements (let them appear earlier or later). This can also be percentage based by adding a '%' at the end
    invertBottomOffset: true, // Add the offset as a negative number to the element's bottom
    repeat: false, // Add the possibility to remove the class if the elements are not visible
    callbackFunction: function(elem, action){}, // Callback to do after a class was added to an element. Action will return "add" or "remove", depending if the class was added or removed
    scrollHorizontal: false 
});
```

There have any way to hold to remove class for 5 second only on class `.a` I means ViewportChecker will remove class immediately, so i want to hold this class `.invisible` for 5 second only on `<div class="a invisible">`.

Comment: will setTimeOut  work?

Comment: @sinhayash  i think `setTimeOut` will not work on this case, because of ViewportChecker, it fire when element on the Viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing the given classes and then adding the class after the delay inside the `callbackFunction` using `setTimeout()` will do the job: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/och42noo/12/)**

```
// For Class a
$('.a').viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
    classToRemove: 'invisible', // Class to remove before adding 'classToAdd' to the elements
    offset: 2, // The offset of the elements (let them appear earlier or later). This can also be percentage based by adding a '%' at the end
    invertBottomOffset: true, // Add the offset as a negative number to the element's bottom
    repeat: false, // Add the possibility to remove the class if the elements are not visible
    callbackFunction: function(elem, action){
        $('.a.visible').addClass('invisible').removeClass('visible');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.a.invisible').addClass('visible').removeClass('invisible');
        },5000);
    }, // Callback to do after a class was added to an element. Action will return "add" or "remove", depending if the class was added or removed
    scrollHorizontal: false 
});


// For Class b
$('.b').viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
    classToRemove: 'invisible', // Class to remove before adding 'classToAdd' to the elements
    offset: 2, // The offset of the elements (let them appear earlier or later). This can also be percentage based by adding a '%' at the end
    invertBottomOffset: true, // Add the offset as a negative number to the element's bottom
    repeat: false, // Add the possibility to remove the class if the elements are not visible
    callbackFunction: function(elem, action){
        $('.b.visible').addClass('invisible').removeClass('visible');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.b.invisible').addClass('visible').removeClass('invisible');
        },5000);
    }, // Callback to do after a class was added to an element. Action will return "add" or "remove", depending if the class was added or removed
    scrollHorizontal: false
});
```